# Mostrar template de acordo com status do usuario

Tags: javascript, firebase, angular, angular-fire-2

estou desenvolvendo um sistema mas estou com dificuldades na parte de autenticação, ou melhor, não necessariamente na parte de autenticação, mas sim na parte de mostrar ou não determinado conteúdo de acordo com o status do usuário (logado ou não).

Basicamente, eu estou fazendo o controle utilizando o ngIF, que chama um método que verifica se o usuário está logado ou não, se tiver chama a home, se não chama o login, até ai tudo bem, ta funcionando sem problema.

O problema é quando o usuário faz login, quando eu atualizo a página primeiramente mostra a tela de login pra só então mostrar a home do site, e algo relativamente rápido, mostra o login e depois a home, o que eu quero e tentar sincronizar isso, por assim dizer, eu quero testar o status do usuário e dependendo do resultado mostrar a home ou o login.

app.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
<cma-header></cma-header>
<cma-sidebar></cma-sidebar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
<cma-login></cma-login>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AuthService } from './autenticacao/autenticacao.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
selector: 'cma-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

public user$ = this.authService.user;
public isLoggedIn;

constructor (private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
success => this.isLoggedIn = success,
  error => console.log(this.isLoggedIn)
);
}

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

Comment: Da uma olhada na documentação de Route Guards -> https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar o:

```
authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
success => this.isLoggedIn = success,
  error => console.log(this.isLoggedIn)
);
```

dentro do `ngOnInit()`